# jquery button validation

Tags: jquery

What wrong with this validation:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#addcmd").attr("disabled","disabled");

    $("#cmdstxt").keypress( function(event){
        var txt=$("#cmdstxt");



        if( txt.val().length > 8 ){
            $("#addcmd").attr("disabled",false);

        }
        else{
        $("#addcmd").attr("disabled","disabled");   
        }
    });       });
```

Html code:

```
<textarea class="element"  name="about" id="cmdstxt"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="addcmd" value="Add comment"  />
```

Here my problem is the button enable only after 10 char disabled only when 7 char in text box how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: besides the fact that `lenght` is mispelt?

Comment: solved the problem using .keyup(); thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rsYN8/)**

You have wrong spelling of length in condition for enabling button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#addcmd").attr("disabled","disabled");

    $("#cmdstxt").keypress( function(event){
        var txt=$("#cmdstxt");
        //alert(txt.val().length);  this alert successfully 
        if( txt.val().length > 7 ){
            $("#addcmd").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });      });​
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and interest to answer my question . Now onwards i will try to be more careful while coding.

Comment: You are welcome, it happens some time we stuck in simple things

Answer (score 2):

misspelled length

```
if( txt.val().lenght > 7 ){
    $("#addcmd").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```